# Text file count returning as 2 when there only one array

Tags: php, json, file, count

Could someone please tell me when the decoded contents returns as count = 2 instead of 1?

I presume if the decode array was there then it should be a count of 1 because it's not got multiple array objects inside it.

Example:

```
// Count 1
Array ( [chat_id] => 414 [inserted] => 1500038898 )

// Count 2 
Array ( 
[0] => Array ([chat_id] => 414 [inserted] => 1500038898) 
[1] => Array ([chat_id] => 415 [inserted] => 1500038898) 
)
```

Text file contents:

```
{"chat_id":414,"inserted":1500038898}
```

Code:

```
// Get file contents
$fileContents = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);

if($fileContents !== NULL){
    // Push decoded contents to temp array
    $decoded_data = $fileContents;
    print_r(count($decoded_data));
}
```

Decoded:

```
Array ( [chat_id] => 414 [inserted] => 1500038898 )
```

Comment: It is counting the last empty line as well, may be? But since it has two keys, it is using them? Also, it is not enclosed by `[]`, which is the array notation.

Comment: Ask yourself - __why__ should it return 1?

Comment: why you think it should return 1?

Comment: `var_dump($decoded_data);die;`

Comment: `count — Count all elements in an array, or something in an object` Any questions?

Comment: To get count 1 you need `Array ([0] => Array( [chat_id] => 414 [inserted] => 1500038898 ) )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dude, as I told you in [my first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45104404/text-file-count-returning-as-2-when-there-only-one-array/45104604#comment77179844_45104404), it is not an array that's there in the JSON. Okay, so JSON data is not upto your input's requirement. Change your JSON data to:

```
[{"chat_id":414,"inserted":1500038898}]
```

This should give you `1` instead of `2`. The above is what you need for single entry. An example of two records, like how you wanted might be looking like:

```
[{"chat_id":414,"inserted":1500038898}, {"chat_id":415,"inserted":1500038898}]
```

I hope I was clear in explaining. You are missing `[]`. It should be an array of objects `[{}]` not just an object `{}`.